# Can a REST resource point/wrap another external REST API?

Tags: rest, http, uri, restful-url

I would like to have a URI like this `/car/toyota`, however I don't want the car resource to map to a database table for example. Instead I would like `car` to just be resource that is used for information retrieval only (ie. no `POST`, `PUT`, or `DELETE` on it), and `/car/toyota/` would retrieve that data somewhere else, say through another REST API on another web server that provides this information.

Is this good design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably belongs on something more like https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

That said, this question depends entirely on the infrastructure of the environment you're making your REST requests on. If you have the ability to control the REST API on the web server providing the information, there's really no reason to wrap that API in another API. All of the call forwarding and potential necessity to translate from one request format to another really just adds un-necessary overhead.

That said, if you're accessing an API that you have no ability to re-format, or if you're accessing an API that you don't want client servers talking to directly, then there's a potential design perk for wrapping a different REST API in your own read only API.

Unfortunately, without having a clear picture of the entire architecture and the problem you're trying to solve, it's pretty difficult to decide if a wrapped API is a good design or not. My only advice is the preferred approach would be to edit the existing API if you can, but that isn't always practical.